# Remix the string based on array

Tags: php

I have a simple whiteboard question:

> > Create a function that takes both a string and an array of numbers as arguments. Rearrange the letters in the string to be in the order
> > specified by the index numbers. Return the "remixed" string. Examples
>
> remix("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]) ➞ "adbc"

I submitted my code but it's not being accepted and I am unable to see why. I wrote:

```
function remix($str, $arr) {

  $strArr = str_split($str);

  for($i = 0; $i < count($strArr); $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = $strArr[$arr[$i]];
  }

  return implode("", $arr);

} 

remix("computer", [0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4]); // ➞ "cmourpte"
```

Can anyone see something wrong with it? It's always regular characters, no special cases FYI. Very confused.

Comment: Well, i would know how to do this in Java or C#, maybe you could better use a foreach and substring
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Your code returns `cmotperu`

Comment: All is correct - at index 5 (considering 0-indexing) is `t` and not `u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the assignment part is putting the value the wrong way round (i.e. it should be assigning the char at position `$i` to `$arr[$i]`)...

```
function remix($str, $arr) {
    $strArr = str_split($str);
    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($strArr); $i++) {
        $strArr[$arr[$i]] = $str[$i];
    }
    
    return implode("", $strArr);
}
```

which for

```
echo remix("PlOt", [1, 3, 0, 2]).PHP_EOL;
echo remix("computer", [0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4]);
```

gives

```
OPtl
cmourpte
```

Just to check, this passes the test.

Comment: Thank you, very clear answer. Although isn't the first test case wrong? Being `remix("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]) ➞ "acdb"`? Shouldn't it be **adbc**?

Comment: This is the issue, the problem states `"a" at index 0, "b" at index 3, "c" at index 1, "d" at index 2` so rather than being the position in the start array, they are the position in the end string.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would seem you missed that the remix was giving an incorrect result.

But I would have done it this way as by default a PHP String is in fact an array already.

```
function remix($str, $arr) {

  $mixed = '';

  foreach ($arr as $i) {
    $mixed .= $str[$i];
  }

  return $mixed;
} 

echo remix("computer", [0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4]);
```

RESULT

```
cmotperu
```

In fact if this is the question, the stated answers are wrong in **ALL** cases.

```
Create a function that takes both a string and an array of numbers as arguments. 
Rearrange the letters in the string to be in the order specified by the index numbers. 
Return the "remixed" string.

Examples

remix("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]) ➞ "acdb"

The string you'll be returning will have: "a" at index 0, "b" at index 3, "c" at index 1, "d" at index 2, because the order of those characters maps to their corresponding numbers in the index array.

remix("PlOt", [1, 3, 0, 2]) ➞ "OPtl"
remix("computer", [0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4]) ➞ "cmourpte"
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But why is it not passing the test then? Here is the question: https://edabit.com/challenge/38rrCC4iynxsH5ZSr

Comment: Have a look at https://edabit.com/challenge/38rrCC4iynxsH5ZSr Looks like someone goofed when asking that question